# Determining latest date from a list

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to determine the latest date from a list of dates that I have stored in my dataframe.  The problem is that I don't know how to compare a list of datetime elements using pandas.

Essentially I'm trying to do the following.

Given this dataset, `Dates` (or something like it)

```
  Date
0 1985-4-5
1 1985-2-9
2 1983-2-2
3 1998-1-12    

n=0
while(n<4):
   if Dates[n]['Date'] is-earlier-than Dates[n+1]['Date']
      latest=Dates[n+1]['Date']
   else:
      latest=Dates[n]['Date']
   n=n+1
```

How can I replace the `is-earlier-than` with something that's actually meaningful to Python?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Date` column is of dtype `datetime64[ns]`, then you could use the `max` method:

```
In [35]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(['1985-4-5', '1985-2-9', '1983-2-2', '1998-1-12'])})
In [44]: df
Out[44]: 
        Date
0 1985-04-05
1 1985-02-09
2 1983-02-02
3 1998-01-12

[4 rows x 1 columns]

In [45]: latest = df['Date'].max()

In [46]: print(latest)
1998-01-12 00:00:00
```

If your `Date` column is composed of strings, then first convert them to `datetime64[ns]` objects:

```
In [47]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['1985-4-5', '1985-2-9', '1983-2-2', '1998-1-12']})

In [48]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

In [49]: df['Date'].max()
Out[49]: Timestamp('1998-01-12 00:00:00')
```

---

If you want to fix the max among the first 4 dates only, then you could slice the Series before calling the `max` method:

```
In [51]: df['Date'][:4].max()
Out[51]: Timestamp('1998-01-12 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html) module and [`sorted(iterable[, cmp[, key[, reverse]]])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function  with reverse = true and `key` argument to convent string into datetime object , at zero index you will get latest date check following code (read comments):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dates = ['1985-4-5', '1985-2-9', '1983-2-2', '1998-1-12'  ]
>>> sorted(
...    dates,  # list of dates input 
...    key = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'),  
...        # convert each string into date
...    reverse=True  # for decreasing order 
... )
['1998-1-12', '1985-4-5', '1985-2-9', '1983-2-2']
>>> sorted(
...    dates,  # list of dates input 
...    key = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'),  
...        # convert each string into date
...    reverse=True  # for decreasing order 
... )[0]
'1998-1-12' # latest
```

You can also use [`max(iterable[, key]))`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function as:

```
>>> max(dates, key= lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'))
'1998-1-12'
>>> min(dates, key= lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'))
'1983-2-2'
```

Check [`classmethod datetime.strptime(date_string, format)¶`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to return a datetime corresponding to date_string, parsed according to format.